# Using Ng-repeat in table, alternatives to multiple tbody?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have multiple objects, and for each object I am trying to generate multiple rows. Please see the code snippet:

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" style="background:whitesmoke; font-size:17px; font-weight: 500">
        Release Criteria <span ng-if="$ctrl.casesModalState.IsEditingCase"> <button ng-click="$ctrl.openCriteriaModal()" type="button" style="float:right; border:none; color: mediumblue; background-color:transparent; margin-right:15px; font-weight:500; font-size: 14px !important"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="margin-right:5px"></i>Add Criteria</button></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody ng-repeat="caseObj in $ctrl.businessCaseService.selectedCase.listOfActiveBusinessCriteria track by $index">
    <tr>
      <td class="criteriaHeader">{{caseObj.criteriaHeader}}</td>
      <td class="valueHeader">{{caseObj.criteriaValueHeader}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="criteriaObj in caseObj.criteriaOptions track by $index">
      <td class="valueLabel">{{criteriaObj.criteriaLabel}}</td>
      <td class="valueClass" ng-attr-id="{{'listIndexValue-' + $index}}" contenteditable="false">{{criteriaObj.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This actually does what I want it to, but it isn't good to have multiple tbody. I can't use a div here to put my ng-repeat in, so I'm not sure what other options I have. Attached an image of the rendered table. This is exactly what I want, but without the multiple tbody.

[image]

Comment: It might help to see the JSON structure, but i'm having a hard time seeing why you couldn't achieve this layout with <div> elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat-start` with `ng-repeat-end` to make the two `tr` be treated as one by the `ng-repeat`:

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.objects = [{
      type: "MoU",
      children: [{
        label: "yes",
        value: 0
      }, {
        label: "no",
        value: 0
      }],
    },
    {
      type: "Incentive",
      children: [{
        label: "yes",
        value: 1
      }, {
        label: "no",
        value: 1
      }],
    },
    {
      type: "Impact",
      children: [{
        label: "yes",
        value: 1
      }, {
        label: "no",
        value: 1
      }],
    }
  ];
}

const app = angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", myCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%" ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl as $ctrl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">
        Release Criteria
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="caseObj in objects">
      <td class="criteriaHeader">{{caseObj.type}}</td>
      <td class="valueHeader">{{caseObj.children.length}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="child in caseObj.children track by $index">
      <td>{{child.label}}</td>
      <td ng-attr-id="{{'listIndexValue-' + $index}}">{{child.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```